# Is there a Typescript-Eslint rule on property access on optional property?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

```
interface TypeA {
    optionalObj?: { prop: string }
}

const a: TypeA = {};

console.log(a.optionalObj.prop);
```

I want to find a Typescript-Eslint rule that will error on the line `a.optionalObj.prop`, because optionalObj can be undefined.

Is there such a rule?

Comment: No, because that is handled by the typescript compiler. Enable strict Mode and typescript will force you to check for null/undefined.

Answer (score 1):

This should be caught as a TS Error `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.`

If you're not seeing this error, fix your `tsconfig.json`. You should turn `strictNullChecks` on. Consider below flags.

```
   "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
```

Comment: `alwaysStrict` is redundant if you have `strict: true`.